# Difference between chart, plot and graph

Tags: user-interface, terminology

I'm thinking of what would be the right terms to use in the UI of my new program, when referring to graphical data representations - i.e., whether to call them "charts", "plots" or "graphs". I was wondering how these terms are different, and when is it appropriate to use each of them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about terminology; not code. UX.SE or English.SE would be better fits for this question.

Comment: Skip to here: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43027/8278

Answer (score 10):

- **Chart**: Bar, line, or pie charts.

[image: bar chart]
<sub>(source: [jpowered.com](http://www.jpowered.com/graph_chart_collection/graph-images/bar-chart.gif))</sub>
 [image: pie chart]
<sub>(source: [jpowered.com](http://www.jpowered.com/php-scripts/pie-chart/images/pie-chart-small.png))</sub>

- **Plot**: X-Y plot or blueprints.

[image: x-y plot]
<sub>(source: [grass.itc.it](http://grass.itc.it/statsgrass/xyplot.jpg))</sub>

- **Graph**: Nodes connected by edges.

[image: graph]
<sub>(source: [graphviz.org](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/process.png))</sub>

Comment: You're describing one kind of graph which has a completely different meaning than "graph" as OP was clearly asking about. It's as though the OP asked on tennis.stackexchange.com "What's the difference between a game, a set, and a match" and you linked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29

Comment: yes, but it also shows that we need a better explanations, emphasizing the differences...

Answer (score 4):

I feel your pain. Google searching on these words lately for software libraries was quite difficult due to the overlap in their usage.

Elementary school kids are [taught](http://nces.ed.gov/nceskids/createAgraph/default.aspx) that "graphs" are two dimensional grids used for "graphically" displaying math functions. Yet "graph theory" is about networks, not functions; see [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Business graphics calls a representation using symbols a "chart," such as a pie chart or bar chart, yet a [stripchart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart_recorder) is a type of plot.